# What's the meaning of "becoming one"?

Tags: meaning

I've read this expression in a context that makes me speculate it means something along the lines of "having sex", but I believe it's supposed to be a more intimate expression.

Since I couldn't find something online that proves my speculation true, I decided to post my question here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the context.  Can you post an excerpt containing the phrase?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: "Root, I can feel the warmth of your hand. We're robots, so that's weird, right? Still, my heart flutters when I'm with you. Electricity ran between us when I touched you. A great energy was born within me, and when I **became one with you**, I thought I had become human."

I do know that since these two persons are robots, having sex shouldn't usually be the first thing that comes to mind. But since it's just fiction, I thought it could be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **become one** is to **combine** in **unison** and **harmony**.

It can have many different usages

> become one with nature
>   become one with the universe
>   two shall become one *(Mark 10:8)*
>   become one with each other

any **disharmony** would cause the whole to collapse.

In reference to your thought, there is a difference between **having sex** and **making love**, in the latter the partners emotionally and spiritually **become one** in the **experience**.  However, it is not necessary to have physical sex for this to occur.

An example of **becoming one**... **Faithless**... Brixton... [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbkJxAsRWyQ)